# X axis labels overlap tooltip in column chart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have a stacked column chart. I can have long strings as labels on x axis so I have used formatter that trims string and shows full string on tooltip. Problem is when I mouseover the columns, the x axis labels and tooltip content overlaps which looks ugly. I want tooltip background fully opaque. It works fine when I do `useHTML false` for labels but by doing this I cannot use html tags for labels. Please suggest some solution with  `useHTML true`.

Here is fiddle showing the problem
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mznaybs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply increase the height of the highcharts and set backgroundColor of tooltip as transparent.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mznaybs/11/

```
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        height : 300
    },
     tooltip: {
        borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
            borderRadius: 05,
            shadow: false,
            useHTML: true,
            percentageDecimals: 2,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y +     '<br/>' +
                'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        },

    },
```

And CSS as:

```
 .label {
     z-index: 1 !important;
 }

.highcharts-tooltip span {
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid green;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:9999 !important;
}

.tooltip {
    padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: I have limited space, I have made height lesser intentionally.

Comment: U can make backgroundcolor of tooltip as transparent . Check my updated answer.

Comment: Its already transparent. I want it opaque so that text behind it hides

Comment: It will make background color black.

Comment: I have tried that one also, It solves the problem to some extent but it looks ugly than it was previous

Comment: Got it as desired after setting `borderWidth: 1`, and removing  `border:1px solid green` from css. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the useHTML: true from xAxis - labels. Since you are only styling the tooltip. Then your good

Comment: I was assuming you wanted to style the tooltip not the xAxis labels.

Comment: Why don't you remove useHTML on both the tooltip and labels and use style tag for styling? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwavg/4mznaybs/6/)

Comment: I can, but I am using useHTML because I want a title attribute for labels that will show on hover.